# How to test Apollo client cache.modify?

Tags: jestjs, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a mutation like so inside a React component:

```js
const DELETE_MEMBERSHIP = gql`
  mutation DeleteMembership($id: ID!) {
    deleteMembership(id: $id) {
      id
    }
  }
`

const [deleteMembership] = useMutation(DELETE_MEMBERSHIP, {
    update(cache, { data }) {
      cache.modify({
        id: cache.identify({
          id: workspaceId,
          __typename: "Workspace",
        }),
        fields: {
          memberships: (existingMemberships, { readField }) =>
            existingMemberships.filter(
              keyRef => data?.deleteMembership.id !== readField("id", keyRef)
            ),
        },
      })
    },
  })
```

In the browser this works as expected, the cache and page updates.

If I test this I can see that the cache isn't being updated and the membership doesn't disappear from the page.

Code coverage with jest shows that the `memberships` fields function is not called inside `cache.modify`.